# sql select only when there is two way relationship for user

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm doing all the tests here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85d6d/1

I tried:

```
SELECT f1.asked_user_id AS friend_id
FROM friends AS f1 JOIN friends AS f2
    USING (asked_user_id)
WHERE f1.asker_user_id = 3 AND f2.asker_user_id = 3 
    AND f1.status = 1 AND f2.status = 1
```

But result was not satisfactory, returned friend_id wasn't always two way.

I've: (3,2,1)
and   (2,3,0)

Thus user_id 3 has no two way friend, so no result should be displayed. But with my query it still comes up.

by two way friendship I mean:

(1,2,1)
(2,1,1)
where: asker,asked,status

Comment: so you want all users that have only two ways friends?

Comment: @wxyz no, I want friends of current user. But friend is defined as two way. I'm not sure if it makes sense :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT f1.asked_user_id AS friend_id
FROM friends AS f1 JOIN friends AS f2
    ON f1.asked_user_id = f2.asker_user_id
   AND f1.asker_user_id = f2.asked_user_id
WHERE f1.status = 1 AND f2.status = 1
```

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85d6d/6)

Comment: Thanks so much for this. This returns all users that have two way relationship right? I want to show current users friends...

Comment: just add condition for current user to this query like this: ....  and f1.asker_user_id = 2

Comment: Also, I like 'initiator' and 'reciprocator'... has a nice ring to it.

Comment: @wxyz hey what about selecting pending requests for current user? How do I exclude double friends from that list?